# Hidden Process Discovered in Tails OS

Tags: rootkits, process

How concerned should I be about this result from unhide?

> unhide-linux scan starting at: 17:02:43, 2020-03-23 Used options:
>   logtofile  [*]Searching for Hidden processes through /proc stat
>   scanning
>
> [*]Searching for Hidden processes through /proc chdir scanning
>
> [*]Searching for Hidden processes through /proc opendir scanning
>
> [*]Searching for Hidden thread through /proc/pid/task readdir scanning
>
> [*]Starting scanning using brute force against PIDS with fork()
>
> Found HIDDEN PID: 20540   Cmdline: ""   Executable: ""
>     "  ... maybe a transitory process" [*]Starting scanning using
>   brute force against PIDS with pthread functions
>
> [*]Searching for Fake processes by verifying that all threads seen by
>   ps are also seen by others
>
> [*]Searching for Hidden processes through sysinfo() scanning
>
> 1 HIDDEN Processes Found    sysinfo.procs reports 565 processes and ps
>   sees 566 processes unhide-linux scan ending at: 17:04:57, 2020-03-23